# Compressor ratio and addition of battery cooling loop (chiller) in the existing HVAC circuit

Tags: hvac, cooling, battery, compressors

Imagine if i want to change my IC car to an electric vehcile, with the obvious addition of  battery, how can i use existing HVAC loop to cool the battery using a chiller. HVAC was obviouly desinged for a specific cooling capacity and a given pressure ratio, will it be possible to know if addtion of a chiller line in the PV diagram in addition to the already existing evaporator line will require retuning or change of the compressor ? For example original cooling capacity was 10kW, cabin cooling load is 5kW so how can make use of remaining 5kW cooling capacity to cool my battery ?
thanks

Comment: That's a huge waste of energy.  The newer Teslas use a heat-pump system to control the temperature of the fluid system which moderates battery temperatures.

Comment: You planning on keeping the existing engine to run the AC?

Comment: @TigerGuy no, not to keep the existing IC engine

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from running water over the evaporator (or installing 2 evaporators)  but I think you'll find that cabin load versus battery load will be quite different.  Probably easiest to install 2 separate system with their own electric motors.

Comment: Why not run a separate loop (e.g. a chilled water loop) between the refrig. line and the battery. Yes there will be a delta-T between the refrig. and CW, but you won't have to mess with the refrig. line and risk venting refrig. It would also mean no additional charge and no changes to the refrig. pressure drop.